# Isotope Append Ajax Request

Tags: jquery, jquery-isotope

Been trying for a while, using the suggestions on Stack Overflow as well as other websites but I can not get this to work 100%;

Could anyone shed how to get the append to work on an ajax call on isotope.

Here is my code.

```
var $grid = jQuery('.pro-main').isotope({
    itemSelector: '.showportfolio',
    percentPosition: true,
    masonry: {
        columnWidth: '.showportfolio'
    }
});

var xxxForm = {
    'id': galID,
    'last': galLast,
    'next': nextNum,
    'version': GalVers,
    'radius': galRad
};

$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '/wp-content/plugins/xxxxxxxxx/xxxxxxxxx/ajax-frontend.php',
    data: xxxForm,
    dataType: 'html',
    encode: true
}).done(function(data) {

    $grid.append(data[0]).isotope('appended', data[0]);

});
```

The ajax call just brings back the div elements.

Thanks for any help that I receive :)

Answer (score 1):

Found out that I was completely over complicating things and you can see the by this:

```
var xxxForm = {
    'id' : galID,
    'last' : galLast,
    'next' : nextNum,
    'version' : GalVers,
    'radius' : galRad
};

$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '/wp-content/plugins/xxxx/xxxxxxx/ajax-frontend.php',
    data: xxxForm,
    dataType: 'html',
    encode: true
}).done(function(data) {

    var $newItems = $(data[0]);
    $('.pro-main').append( $newItems ).isotope( 'insert', $newItems );

});
```